# Ethernet Interfaces missing in RHEL 8

Tags: network-interface

Earlier there was nothing in Network-scripts directory, but after installing network-scripts from ISO almost all files came and network interfaces went missing in RHEL 8 VM.

Network interfaces missing in rhel8

I have tried adding ethernet device using nmtui, it creates file but after restarting network service getting error "Device not found".

```
Feb 28 12:02:57 localhost.localdomain network[9163]: 'network-scripts' will be removed>
Feb 28 12:02:57 localhost.localdomain network[9164]: It is advised to switch to 'Netwo>
Feb 28 12:03:00 localhost.localdomain NET[9284]: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-p>
Feb 28 12:03:00 localhost.localdomain network[9149]: [46B blob data]
Feb 28 12:03:01 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[7515]: <info>  [1582909381.5032] >
Feb 28 12:03:01 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[7515]: <info>  [1582909381.5842] >
Feb 28 12:03:01 localhost.localdomain network[9149]: Bringing up interface enp0s3:  Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device found for this connection (device virbr0 not available because profile is not available because profile is not compatible with device (mismatching interface name)).>
Feb 28 12:03:01 localhost.localdomain network[9149]: [13B blob data]
Feb 28 12:03:01 localhost.localdomain network[9149]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 28 12:03:01 localhost.localdomain network[9149]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 28 12:03:01 localhost.localdomain network[9149]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 28 12:03:01 localhost.localdomain network[9149]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 28 12:03:01 localhost.localdomain network[9149]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 28 12:03:01 localhost.localdomain network[9149]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 28 12:03:01 localhost.localdomain network[9149]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 28 12:03:01 localhost.localdomain network[9149]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 28 12:03:01 localhost.localdomain network[9149]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 28 12:03:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: network.service: Control process exi>
Feb 28 12:03:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: network.service: Failed with result >
Feb 28 12:03:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down n>
-- Subject: Unit network.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
-- 
-- Unit network.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
lines 1389-1415/1415 (END)
```

After Adding Device[image]

Added from comment: output of `ip link`:

```
[root@localhost network-scripts]# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:21:d2:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:21:d2:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[root@localhost network-scripts]#
```

```
Thanks for your reply A B,
There is no change in Hardware or Accidental damage. i was able to use same VM 3-4 months ago. suddenly network was not working. i tried installing new VM with RHEL8, still same issue.

Adding Output of #lspci -n -n

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX Host bridge [8086:7190] (rev 01)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX AGP bridge [8086:7191] (rev 01)
00:07.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ISA [8086:7110] (rev 08)
00:07.1 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE [8086:7111] (rev 01)
00:07.3 Bridge [0680]: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI [8086:7113] (rev 08)
00:07.7 System peripheral [0880]: VMware Virtual Machine Communication Interface [15ad:0740] (rev 10)
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: VMware SVGA II Adapter [15ad:0405]
00:10.0 SCSI storage controller [0100]: BusLogic BT-946C (BA80C30) [MultiMaster 10] [104b:1040] (rev 01)
00:11.0 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI bridge [15ad:0790] (rev 02)
00:15.0 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:15.1 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:15.2 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:15.3 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:15.4 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:15.5 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:15.6 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:15.7 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:16.0 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:16.1 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:16.2 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:16.3 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:16.4 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:16.5 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:16.6 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:16.7 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:17.0 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:17.1 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:17.2 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:17.3 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:17.4 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:17.5 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:17.6 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:17.7 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:18.0 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:18.1 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:18.2 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:18.3 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:18.4 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:18.5 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:18.6 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
00:18.7 PCI bridge [0604]: VMware PCI Express Root Port [15ad:07a0] (rev 01)
02:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: VMware USB1.1 UHCI Controller [15ad:0774]
02:01.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE] [1022:2000] (rev 10)
02:02.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Ensoniq ES1371/ES1373 / Creative Labs CT2518 [1274:1371] (rev 02)
02:03.0 USB controller [0c03]: VMware USB2 EHCI Controller [15ad:0770]
02:05.0 SATA controller [0106]: VMware SATA AHCI controller [15ad:07e0]
02:06.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 79c970 [PCnet32 LANCE] [1022:2000] (rev 10)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: (sorry didn't see there was an other edit suggestion during my edit). @Linux Admin. You're using an obsolete command: `ifconfig` and in the wrong way (without `-a`). Please add the result of the command `ip link` instead.

Comment: [root@localhost network-scripts]# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:21:d2:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:21:d2:2f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[root@localhost network-scripts]#

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to forum. unable to add images and comment more than 600 letters. please help to solve this issue.

Comment: I failed to read it was about a VM (the screen shot...) It appears there are two ethernet controllers. That means there's no driver available for them provided by your RHEL 8 installation. Rather than trying to find how to have these specific drivers available, you could instead try to change them to VMXNET 3 network adapter type on the host's configuration for this VM.

Comment: also check: https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=software&details=1&partner=75&networking=1&page=1&display_interval=10&sortColumn=Partner&sortOrder=Asc&testConfig=16 . There's no support by/for RHEL8. So the answer is about VMware, which I'd consider off topic here, so I won't write an answer. VMXNET 3 is supported by/for RHEL8.

Comment: I just had this exact same issue. NICs suddenly disappeared in RHEL 8.4 VM, even though set to VMXNET3. lspci reports them as being there, but they just weren't getting bound to any interfaces in the OS. I plugged in a USB ethernet adapter and magically the other NICs came back. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this (or something similar) after upgrading an old RedHat instance to RHEL 7. A couple of network-related servcices were failing at boot. They would time out, so my system wasn't prevented from booting up, but it wasn't getting any network connectivity.

EDIT: My previous solution was incomplete and failed the next time I had to apply it. Here's what appears now to be the complete solution.

I found this article from Red Hat describing the problem and a solution which worked for me: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2592561
The article describes very accurately my situation: upgrading a VMWare guest from 6 to 7, using a DVD ISO image which didn't include their "errata" which would have prevented this problem.

I ended up running these commands:

```bash
nmcli connection modify 'System eth0' connection.interface-name ens192
nmcli connection modify 'System eth0' connection.id ens192
nmcli connection up ens192
```

Rebooted and the system was happy again!